# How to hide 2nd monitor from a Software that is preventing multiple display devices

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display

I have a software that prevents me to connect to any additional monitor, the software is preventing it to **avoid any piracy** or recording of the content it has, although my only intention is to use my big monitor. How this can be achieved.

The Error it shows is : display_count = 2

Edit - Operating System = Windows

Software = It's a university software based on e-learning.

As I said, the software displays the error: display_count=2 as soon as I plug in my HDMI cable. I want to use my 2nd monitor as it is. My understanding is that since it is a subscription-based e-learning platform it doesn't want anyone to record the videos, so it also shuts down any other window (i.e browser, explorer, etc) as soon as I open this software.

Comment: Turning off the 2nd monitor doesn't resolve the problem?

Comment: @harrymc I want to use my external display. i.e My laptop is connected to the monitor using HDMI cable and the software is preventing it. I want to bypass this.

Comment: @pigeonburger software is of an institution, not for public usage since it contains videos of domain courses.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have updated the os and what exactly this software is, hope you'll be able to answer now.

Comment: @ultraverse_in this still doesn't tell us the name of the program.

Comment: Ahhh… one of those things. I'd install anything like that on a VM if it will run on one. These things are often built by … let's call them "well-intentioned" people...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Device Manager to disable the built-in display adapter just before you call this software. This way you will only have one display when running
the software.

In the worst case that your computer crashes with the adapter still disabled,
it will be automatically re-enabled on reboot. (Although it's safer
to re-enable it before shutting down the computer.)